# User Deprecated: The "fos_user.change_password.form.factory" service is private

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am getting following error. I am using symfony 3.4 and fos bundle. This error arose on password change route. Please if some can help quickly. I am in little bit hurry.

[image]

Comment: You can click the link to see the image. Actually I am new on stackoverflow, and this post editing went little bit odd

Comment: Next time please take some time to create valuable question before posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to get the form factory in your controller like this:

```
$this->get('fos_user.change_password.form.factory');
```

In symfony, you can define [services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html), which are classes that symfony will create when requested. They are usually defined in

- config/services.yaml
- config/services.xml
- or config/services.php

Services can have other services as their arguments, e.g. in yaml:

```
serviceA:
    class: AppBundle\Service\ServiceA
    arguments:
        $email: 'test@domain.com'
serviceB:
    class: AppBundle\Service\ServiceB
    arguments:
        $serviceA: '@serviceA'
```

> The @ symbol is important: that's what tells the container you want to pass the service whose id is serviceA and not just the string "serviceA"

The services definition would be:

```
class serviceA {

    public function __construct($email) {

    }
}

class serviceB {

    public function __construct(ServiceA $serviceA) {

    }
}
```

In this case, serviceA is a dependency for serviceB, meaning that symfony upon creating serviceB will also create serviceA(if it was not yet created) and provide it to serviceB `s constructor.

Services are declared either as **private or public**: [public vs private services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#public-versus-private-services).

**Since symfony 3.4**, services are private by default: [symfony 3.4 service changes](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default)

You cannot access private services directly through the service container, you have to inject them to other services or your controllers(by defining your controllers as services).

If you want to use it in your controller eg. **MyController**, first define your controller as a service:

```
AppBundle\Controller\MyController:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\MyController
    public: true
    arguments:
        $formFactory: '@fos_user.change_password.form.factory'
```

and change the controller to:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FormFactory;

/**
 * @Route(service="AppBundle\Controller\MyController")
*/
class MyController {

    private $changePasswordFormFactory;
    public function __construct(FormFactory $formFactory) {
         $this->changePasswordFormFactory = $formFactory;
    }
}
```

[FOS user bundle change password service configuration](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/change_password.xml)

Interestingly, the same was requested at the FOS user bundle repo, was merged but then it was reverted:

[Pull request](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/pull/2699)
[Issue comment](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/pull/2691#issuecomment-366207712)

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error. 
It's a warning and the message is pretty self explanatory I reckon.

Without seeing your code I can't be sure what wrong but here what I assume:

You must be calling the service via `$container->get('fos_user.change_password.form_factory')` and what the warning say is that this is not anymore the correct way and you should have dependancy injection.

Have a look there to see how it works https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/dependency_injection.html